# Modifying values in a pandas dataframe column given a different column has a desired value

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': 'foo bar foo bar foo bar foo foo'.split(),
               'B': 'one one two three two two one three'.split(),
               'C': np.arange(8), 'D': np.zeros(8)})
```

The output looks like this:

```
print(df)
     A      B  C    D
0  foo    one  0  0.0
1  bar    one  1  0.0
2  foo    two  2  0.0
3  bar  three  3  0.0
4  foo    two  4  0.0
5  bar    two  5  0.0
6  foo    one  6  0.0
7  foo  three  7  0.0
```

What I now want to do is consider column C and if its values are odd numbers, change the corresponding D value to 1 and if they are even, keep it 0.

How do I do that? I am very new to python and I am kind of confused. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Is it:

```
df['D'] = df['C'] % 2
```

Or if current `0` values in `D` are just representative, and you only want to change the specific rows, you can use `loc`:

```
df.loc[(df['C'] % 2)==1, 'D'] = 1
```

Output:

```
     A      B  C  D
0  foo    one  0  0
1  bar    one  1  1
2  foo    two  2  0
3  bar  three  3  1
4  foo    two  4  0
5  bar    two  5  1
6  foo    one  6  0
7  foo  three  7  1
```

Comment: Did the job for me. Thanks a lot. :) I was looking for the second one.